# "On the contrary" or "In contrast"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

> However, nothing in the recent studies has carried any imputation
> against vaccines. **On the contrary,** based on empirical evidence, it
> seems that immunising people has decreased mortality rate and
> increased life expectancy.

- Is the usage of "On the contrary" correct in this sentence?
- Is "In contrast" a better choice?

Comment: Ignoring the specific example, "on the contrary" always expresses conflict, in which two points of view are clearly opposed. "in contrast" does ask the reader to see the difference, but it doesn't necessarily imply a simple conflict… it prolly should, and I suggest in fact, it doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*On the contrary* is definitely the right phrase here, meaning that the opposite (of the possibility mentioned in the first sentence) is true.

*In contrast* would introduce a comparison between two things that were both real but very different.

Comment: Do two things really need to be *very* different for "In contrast" ? I would also use "in contrast" for things that are different in a subtle but important way.

Comment: _Contrast_ to me implies a very noticeable difference.

Answer (score 1):

"On the contrary" is used following an assertion that something is false, and introduces something that emphasizes and/or supports the assertion that it is false. So there are two claims in the first sentence: an inner one (in this case, "[something] in the recent studies has carried any imputation against vaccines.") and an outer one denying the inner one ("nothing in the recent studies has carried any imputation against vaccines.") "On the contrary" introduces something that supports the outer statement by opposing the inner one. "In contrast" would imply that you're introducing something that opposes the outer statement.

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t make a mistake.  On the contrary, you used “on the contrary” correctly!  It refutes the earlier statement by saying how it isn’t true.

In contrast, “in contrast” introduces an example of something that’s different, without implying that the first statement is untrue of the other thing it’s about.